# PCL 1.8 and PCL 1.10 difference

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, pcl

Could someone please describe what is the difference between:

- `PCL 1.8` used by `Ubuntu 18.04`
- `PCL 1.10` used by `Ubuntu 20.04`

When running the same code on `PCL 1.8`, it works fine or gives expected output. And when I run the same code on `PCL 1.10`, it wasn't able to segment all the required object?

Here is the screenshot for output for PCL 1.10.

[image].

Thank you

Comment: The changelog for PCL since version 1.10 can be found [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/CHANGES.md#-1100-19012020-). Please post the relevant chunk of code to help us help you with determining the potential affected changes.

Comment: Basically, I found the problem. Thank you!